# Polygon/Line/Point-Layer - fill out columns automatically with preset (word/value) when creating entity in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, polygon-creation, column

I have to draw several features like polygons, points and lines by hand in my QGIS project on to defined layers and those layers contain an attribute table with several columns.

Is there any way to set a preset (values/words) of some sort for specific columns which means I don'`t have to fill out the columns by hand when I create an entity?

Below there is an example:

[image]

In this picture I created the polygon and now I have to fill out the attribut table. The layer is categorized and by adding "Colored" in the "Feature" column I get the defined style for this polygon like in the picture below.

[image]

Is it possible to set some sort of preset in the "attribute-formula" or anywhere else?

How can I set this preset exactly?

[image]

I´ve found other Q&As but in my case I don't have any relationship to other layers with any information for the attribute table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'Colored'` would be the correct syntax.

Within Qgis expressions single quotation marks (`'yourtexthere'`) are used to designate input of characters, while double quotation marks (`"yourfieldnamehere"`) are used to reference column/field names.